# How to disable EntityFramework Core migrations?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

**Question**

How do I disable Entity Framework Core Database Migrations?

**Information**

When I created an ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC website with Identity Core (that uses EF Core) I did the following:

1. Changed the connection string to point to a SQL Express instance
2. I opened the website and went to the register screen
3. The database was created automatically

Now I want to ensure nothing else is automatically updated by Database Migrations. I want the control to be able to turn migrations on/off.

The `ApplicationDbContext` doesn't seem to initialize as it has done in the past i.e. that would update the model automatically e.g. `CreateIfNotExists`.

I would actually prefer to make the changes to the SQL server manually rather than risk losing data, sometimes I will happily let it perform the update.

I want the ability to choose.

The following website hints that no magic is performed, the calls to `EnsureCreated` and `Migrate` have to be called - so how do I stop this from being called for ASP.NET Identity i.e. on `ApplicationDbContext`?
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/porting/ensure-requirements.html

I don't mind if there is a create command in ASP.NET Identity Core but how do I know there is not a `Migrate()` method within ASP.NET Identity that affects the shared `ApplicationDbContext` thus affecting tables other than those relating to Identity?

**My environment**

1. VS2015
2. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"
3. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"

I'm probably missing something obvious - so much to keep updated with!

Comment: "but how do I know there is not a Migrate() method within ASP.NET Identity" >>> Look at the source code!

Comment: I tried searching the github source code but im not 100% sure the possible implementation variants to search for.